# Directory(Path) of Android Keystore in an android phone

Tags: java, android, keystore, public-key-encryption, android-keystore

```
KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_EC, "AndroidKeyStore");
        keyGen.initialize(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                "Authentication_Key" + username,
                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_VERIFY)
                .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
                .setKeySize(521)
                .setKeyValidityStart(from)
                .setKeyValidityEnd(to)
                .build());
        KeyPair keyPair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
```

In the above code, the key pair is saved in the Android KeyStore. Does someone know where does the keystore save these keys in the android phone. I have a rooted android phone so I was wondering if these keys can be accessed from some directory in an android phone.

Basically I am looking for the path of Android Keystore in an android phone.

Comment: In hardware.  That's part of why its secure.

Comment: That what I thought. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by Gebe, its in the hardware and that is why it is so secured.